# Is Mandy real in the book "Illusion"?

Tags: illusion

I was reading a science fiction/fantasy book called [*Illusion*](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/12408735-illusion) by Frank E. Peretti and just finished reading it, but I was a bit puzzled.

Was Mandy real or just an illusion? And did Mandy actually lift the table or what?

Comment: Table lifting is a common 'medium' trick, usually accomplished with a thin metal rod hidden in the sleeves

Comment: @Valorum if you read the book in the edited link, later they discuss about it; Sorry if I wasn't being specific. It was like this; so when the person asked Mandy to move the pencil without touching it, Mandy did and then showed a trick. Without touching the table or the stuff on top of it, she was able to lift it into the air. When the person and other men where talking about that trick, they were thinking that she brought several other Mandies from a dimension or something and they lifted it up for her.